# vBulletin BBCode on external page

Tags: bbcode, vbulletin

I integrated my vBulletin with custom front page. I'm wondering, how could I use vBulletin BBcode on that page (I'm displaying some posts there).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably best to just use the BBCode parser from vBulletin itself. It's relatively easy to use, here's an example:

```
require_once('global.php');
require_once('includes/class_bbcode.php');

$parser = new vB_BbCodeParser($vbulletin, fetch_tag_list());
$text = $parser->parse('[B][I]text[/I][/B]');
print $text;
```

You may need to play games with `chdir` to include `global.php` from somewhere outside the vBulletin tree, but I'm sure you've had to do that for other integration anyway. :)

There are way of restricting the tags too, just have a rummage around `class_bbcode.php` and you'll see some fairly obvious places to start.

Comment: Thanks for reply Conor. Already found solution, identical as yours. Anyway, thanks for your help and support!